# Converting a UDF into an array UDF

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, udf

I have checked on how to make single-cell array UDFs and cannot make head nor tail of what I have seen so I thought maybe I had better ask!

I was wondering if anyone could please help me figure out how to convert my UDF to something that can handle a range, the output of which could then be averaged.

I have created a UDF to find the number of months in an age in this format:

```
Chronological Age

    8:1
    8:2
    8:9
    8:1
    8:0
    7:10
    8:9
```

the UDF goes as follows:

```
Function GDAgeToMonths(YearsMonths As String) As Integer

Dim Colonz As Integer, Yearz As Integer, Monthz As Integer, Greaterz As Integer

' check if the stings consists of ">" sign
If InStr(YearsMonths, ">") >= 1 Then
    Greaterz = 2
Else
    Greaterz = 1
End If

' check position of ":" or "." sign
If InStr(YearsMonths, ":") >= 1 Then
    Colonz = InStr(YearsMonths, ":")
Else
    Colonz = InStr(YearsMonths, ".")
End If

Yearz = Mid(YearsMonths, Greaterz, Colonz - Greaterz)
Monthz = Right(YearsMonths, Len(YearsMonths) - Colonz)
GDAgeToMonths = Yearz * 12 + Monthz

End Function
```

So I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
Function GDAverageAge(AgeRange As Range) As Integer

Dim MonthsRange As Range, AverageMonths As Double

MonthsRange = GDAgeToMonths(AgeRange)

AverageMonths = WorksheetFunction.Average(MonthsRange)

GDAverageRange = GDMonthsToAge(AverageMonths)

End Function
```

With the function below to turn the average from months back to an age:

```
Function GDMonthsToAge(NumberofMonths As Integer) As String

Dim Yearz As Integer, Monthz As Integer
Yearz = NumberofMonths \ 12
Monthz = NumberofMonths - (12 * Yearz)
GDMonthsToAge = Yearz & ":" & Monthz
End Function
```

I really hope this makes sense!

I do not really know if it has to be an array formula per se or whether it would do something with a range but I am basically planning to use a formula to average the result of a formula run on each cell in a range.

Any help will be gratefully received!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No UDF has to be an array formula because you build the reiterative calculations within the code for the UDF itself. Also, no UDF can write a value into a cell on the worksheet that is not the cell containing the UDF. However, a series of cells can contain a UDF and be 'array entered' just as any other native worksheet formula can.

Comment: Thank you for that- I think I understand what you mean. The UDF I want to create will take in a range, convert it to months, average it, convert it back to years and then report it in the cell it is written in. Just like when you use the average function within excel except converting each cell to an "averagable" format before performing the average calculation. To put it another way, I want to get the average age from a column of ages. Excel cannot interpret ages in the format above so they need converting to a number of months first but I do not want to create another column for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were kind of close, you just needed a For loop:

```
Function GDAverageAge(Ages As Range) As String
Dim c As Integer, a As Integer, am As Integer, v As Variant
'Counter of number of entries in range
c = 0
'Total value of range in months
a = 0
For Each v In Ages
a = a + GDAgeToMonths(v.Value)
c = c + 1
Next v
am = a / c
GDAverageAge = GDMonthsToAge(am)
End Function
```

Works here- enjoy!